# python timestamp : Find all timestamps as string before 5 mins

Tags: python, timestamp

I have a string like "`201501010003`" representing a timestamp like `YYYYMMDDHHMM`.

I want to go back 5 mins and print all the timestamps for each minute like:

```
201501010002
201501010001
201501010000
201412122359
201412122358
```

Comment: What did you try do far? Your question isn't 100% clear, do you mean you have a list of time stamps and you only want to print the ones that fall in the last 5 minutes from now?

Comment: I have one timestamp and I want go back 5 mins back from this timestamp and print each minute in the same format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
s = "20150101000"
ts = datetime.strptime(s, '%Y%m%d%H%M')
for x in range(1,6):
    (ts - timedelta(minutes=x)).strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')
```

---

Output:

```
'201412312359'
'201412312358'
'201412312357'
'201412312356'
'201412312355'
```

---

This is using the [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) function in a loop to subtract one minute at a time from your string.